# Get list of PK for table in Teradata

Tags: sql, select, primary-key, teradata

How to get the list of primary keys (not indexes) for specific table in Teradata?

I've created table

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TBL_TEMPORAL_TRANSACTTIME
 ( 
  ParID int not null, 
  DataSourceTypeCd VARCHAR(10) not null, 
  TxnPrd PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE) TITLE 'Transaction Period' NOT NULL AS TRANSACTIONTIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(ParID, DataSourceTypeCd ) 
  )  PRIMARY INDEX (ParID);
```

And I need some query to return columns for primary key
So I want to get 'ParID' and 'DataSourceTypeCd'  columns.
Can anyone help me?

I tried

```
SELECT  *
FROM    DBC.IndicesV
WHERE   TABLENAME='TBL_TEMPORAL_TRANSACTTIME'
    AND IndexType = 'K'
;
```

But it gives me empty result.

```
SELECT  IndexType, ColumnName, UniqueOrPK
FROM    DBC.IndicesV
WHERE   TABLENAME='TBL_TEMPORAL_TRANSACTTIME';
```

Returns:

```
IndexType   ColumnName  UniqueOrPK
P   ParID   
J   ParID   K
J   TxnPrd  K
J   DataSourceTypeCd    K
```

Comment: Have you looked at the column UniqueOrPK?

Comment: I get the same behavior for a temporal table.

Comment: It looks like the temporal table got a `J`oin index with the two PK columns + the TRANSACTIONTIME column. And the information, that it is a PrimaryKey too, has moved to the field UniqueOrPK.   Looks like a special case of implementing restrictions in a temporal with PK.  Btw. if you try to add another join index,  you get 'Error in Join Index DDL, current form of join index does not include TransactionTime column.'

Comment: @Rob Paller, I've selected UnoqueOrPK column, but the information does not help me. Maybe there are any other ideas how I can get PK information?

Comment: @Ulick, thank you for the explanation. It seems that it was as you've described. I've selected information from UniqueOrPK too (see question description) but there are no useful information which can help me to identify what columns are Primary Key

Comment: If you define a primary key, you define it to be unique. If the table is temporal, it always may contain multiple rows with that 'unique' key but different values in the transactiontime column. To fullfill the uniqeness requirement, the transactiontime column is added to the KEY as you defined it. If you select from a temporal table, you get the  current version of  a row because it is the default. But other rows with a different transactiontime are still in the table.

Answer (score -1):

Teradata 15.10 Documentation; Data Dictionary, Chapter 3: Views Reference, topic **IndicesV[X]** (Page 164), Heading **IndexType** states that value `K` for IndexType reflects Primary Key.

So following will give you the PK columns:

```
SELECT  ColumnName
FROM    DBC.IndicesV
WHERE   TABLENAME='TBL_TEMPORAL_TRANSACTTIME'
        AND IndexType = 'K'
;
```

Its recommended that you also add `AND DatabaseName = 'YourDBName'` to be more specific about your table.

Comment: I've tried this variant but it is not gives me correct result. It returns empty result set. I've also viewed what is stored in  DBC.IndicesV for 'TBL_TEMPORAL_TRANSACTTIME' table, but allowed IndexTypes are P and J

Comment: It is working for me. I tested on the exact DDL except for Temporal part.

Comment: Please, see updated question description. Maybe the problem is in temporal part? I've also checked for no-temporal tables and it also works for me